# Apache web server: URLs that contain a "." results in "Permission denied"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, netsuite

We are trying to migrate traffic from our old Netsuite store to a newer solution. The last step before launch is configuring the .htaccess file to redirect traffic from the old Netsuite URLs to the new SEF URLs.

**Netsuite URL:**
www.myoldstore.com/s.nl/sc.27/.f

**New URL:**
www.mynewstore.com/store-home-page

For launch, we will point the old domain "www.myoldstore.com" at our new server which is configured to accept traffic for this domain.

I configured the following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myoldstore\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mynewstore.com/store-home-page [L,R=301]
```

However, I just discovered that any traffic on our server (Apache 2) that has a path like the old Netsuite URL (/s.nl/sc.27/.f) generates a "Permission denied" message.

Is there some way to configure either the server or .htaccess to allow/handle paths like that?

---

**UPDATE:** I found the problem. The new site is a Drupal site, and Drupal's default .htaccess file includees the following rule:

```
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
```

That is intended to block access to hidden directories. I didn't want to remove it altogether, so I moved it lower in the .htaccess file so it only processes after the specific old URLs have been handled.

Comment: If you solved it, just delete this question. It's not needed.

Comment: It may still be useful to other netsuite users. Move your edit to an answer and accept it, and add [tag:netsuite].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new site is a Drupal site, and Drupal's default .htaccess file includes the following rule:

```
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
```

That is intended to block access to hidden directories. I didn't want to remove it altogether, so I moved it lower in the .htaccess file so it only processes after the specific old URLs have been handled.